# CSS - Centered container in fixed sticky header

Tags: html, css

I'm having some problems with CSS, Basically i want a main container and a fixed sticky header. The main container has a width of 900px but i want the header to stretch the whole page. I have got this but i also wanted there to be a separate container within the container that is 900 pixels long but within the  header container. Hard to explain but this is what i have so far:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Test</title>
<link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="Header"> 
    <div id="Centerheader">
    This should be centered in the header.
    </div>
</div>

<div id="Main">
This is a test.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#Main {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 900px;
    height: 1200px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #000000;
    margin-top: 120px;
 }

#Header {
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #333333;
    top: 0px;
 }

#Centerheader {
     width: 900px;
     height: 120px;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0px;
     margin-right:auto;
     margin-left: auto;
}

}
```

Hopefully I have explained this well enough.
Thanks,
Skurope

Comment: #Header should be centered relative, and #Centerheader should be centered absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `fixed` position from `#Centerheader` :

```
#Centerheader {
 width: 900px;
 height: 120px;
 /*position: fixed; Remove this*/
 margin:0 auto;
}
```

Check this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xQW5X/2/embedded/result/)**

Comment: Oh.... Thanks very much! So the centered header is staying in the Header? That clears up a lot Thanks! :)

Comment: Yep since is inside the fixed container also stay fixed.